# Cannot get the value of @Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a Create cshtml Page as follows :-

```
@model MvcCommons.ViewModels.CompositeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Article</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleTitle)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleTitle)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleTitle)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleText)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleText)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleText)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleSource)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleSource)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.ArticleSource)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.CategoryID, "Category")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.CategoryID)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

and then I am getting the viewModel inside the Create Action as follows :-

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CompositeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            unitOfWork.ArticleRepository.Insert(viewModel.ArticleViewModel.Article);
            unitOfWork.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        PopulateDropDownList(viewModel.ArticleViewModel.Article.CategoryID);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The PopulateDropDownList code is as follows :-

```
        private void PopulateDropDownList(object selectedCategory = null)
    {
        var categoryQuery = unitOfWork.CategoryRepository.Get(
                        orderBy: q => q.OrderBy(d => d.CategoryTitle));
        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(unitOfWork.CategoryRepository.Get(), "CategoryID", "CategoryTitle", selectedCategory);

    }
```

My problem is that the CategoryID inside the CompositeViewModel viewModel is always 0 no matter what values I choose in the dropdown list! The other data entered in the Create cshtml is filled correctly inside the viewModel.

I cannot spot what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: In the HTML that gets generated for the dropdown, do you have a `name` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using [DropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703573.aspx):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.CategoryID, (SelectList)ViewBag.CategoryID)
```

Comment: I am getting this error now " 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MvcCommons.ViewModels.CompositeViewModel>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. "

Comment: ok worked like this             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ArticleViewModel.Article.CategoryID, (SelectList)ViewBag.CategoryID).  What answer should I accept now since both are valid answers?

Comment: @Johann Ah sorry, yeah `ViewBag.CategoryID` would be `object`, forgot to cast. "*What answer should I accept now...*" that's up to you, go with what answer you think helped you the most.

Comment: not fair on DanielB though cause he contributed a lot too. I gave him a rep, though I have no idea what that means :)

Comment: @Johann both answers give you what you want. If you wanted me to compare answers the only thing I would say is using `DropDownListFor` is more reliable as you are letting the Framework do the work rather than hard-coding the ID in. With @DanielB's answer, if you changed your model you would also need to update your views which is a pain, and easy to miss. It's also more consistent with your existing code.

Comment: Yes I prefered James solution for using the DropDownListFor.  So I did accept the correct answer is that correct?  BTW what is the orange triangle?  Is that a rep?

Comment: @Johann don't beat yourself up about not accepting someone else's answer... I have seen some of my answers overlooked for some pretty bad answers just simply because it gave the OP what they wanted (not necessarily what they need). If it solves your problem then it is the correct answer, if there are multiple which solve your problem then go with the one you prefer. The orange triangle just indicates that you have voted on that particular question/answer. If you want to know how SO works you should go over to the [meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
@Html.DropDownList("ArticleViewModel.Article.CategoryID", ViewBag.CategoryID, null)
```

so ModelBinding works correctly or even use `DropDownListFor<>()`.

Comment: I am getting this error :- "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ArticleViewModel.Article.CategoryID'." I changed the PopulateDropDownList method to include "ArticleViewModel.Article.CategoryID" instead of the "CategoryID" and I also changed it in the cshtml as you suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to set the 2nd parameter to `ViewBag.CategoryID`. I've edited my post.